# Docker SDK Python run container if it isn't aleardy running

Tags: python, docker, http-status-code-404, docker-container, dockerpy

My goal is to only run the container if it isn't already running.

What I tried is using client.containers.get(containername) and checking if it is None but that won't work because it returns an error message and not a bool.

```
if client.containers.get('containername') is not None:
   client.containeres.run("redis:latest",name="containerename", detach=True, ports={'6379/tcp': ('localhost', 6379)})
```

I get:

```
docker.error.notFound: 404 Client Error: Not Found("No such container: containername")
```

Is there any way I can manage to check if the redis container is already running and only run the container if it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

What about to use [containers.list](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.list)?

```
if len(client.containers.list(filters = {'name' : 'containername'})) == 0:
  ...
```